# visual studio code snippet stubs

Tags: xcode, token, code-snippets

Does VS have a code snippet feature, where you can insert a placeholder/stub/token in a snippet, where after expanding the initial shortcut, allows you to tab across the tokens?

If you are familiar with Xcode, Xcode's autocomplete for methods will insert a token for each method parameter after you tab-complete a method.

It would be nice to do that with VS. I know VS allows you to make your own snippets using XML files, but is there a way to have that token? It would make it a lot easier to implement method stubs, class stubs, etc.

Answer (score -1):

the answer for all your questions is yes!.
VS includes a snipepts functionality. you can read all about it in here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392(v=vs.80).aspx